# Guess what I am? I get wet when you're nervous

Tags: riddle

I get wet when you're nervous

I'm weak but can become strong

I'm controlled by strings

I have the same color as you

I get heavier when you get married

You use me everyday

Who am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> A Hand or The ring finger

I get wet when you're nervous:

> [Sweaty hands](https://www.sweathelp.org/where-do-you-sweat/sweaty-hands.html)
>  and the fingers sweat also

I'm weak but can become strong:

> By training at the gym we can build muscles and our hands become stronger

I'm controlled by strings:

> Most The body parts are controlled by strings

I have the same Colour as you:

> The skin on the hands or fingers

I get heavier when you get married:

> The wedding ring makes both the ring finger and hand heavier

You use me everyday:

> you use your hands and fingers every day, you just used it to type this riddle

Comment: That is correct! Ill post harder ones in the future!

Comment: "you just used it to type this riddle"
Actually, he just could type it with his nose

Comment: "Palms are sweaty..."

Comment: I've been working out regularly for 9.5 years and my hands are definitely not stronger.  I call shenanigans!  But +1.